# No puedo extraer el dato completo con sscanf() de un arreglo

Tags: c, stm32

espero estén bien. Tengo un proyecto de electrónica en el cual necesito separar las opciones de un comando las cuales llegan vía I2C como una sola trama, en este caso específico necesito separar el comando para establecer la hora junto con la hora a la que se va a asignar una función específica, para ello ya el API cuenta con un tipo de estructura definida en un archivo XX.h y va como sigue

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t Hours;
    uint8_t Minutes;          
    uint8_t Seconds;          
} RTC_TimeTypeDef;
```

yo creé una estructura de estructuras del tipo RTC_TimeTypeDef con siete miembros de este tipo como se puede observar más abajo

```
typedef struct                      /* Tiempos para comenzar cambios de fase  */
{                                   /* para las 6 fases.                      */
    RTC_TimeTypeDef hSistema;
    RTC_TimeTypeDef tFase1;
    RTC_TimeTypeDef tFase2;
    RTC_TimeTypeDef tFase3;
    RTC_TimeTypeDef tFase4;
    RTC_TimeTypeDef tFase5;
    RTC_TimeTypeDef tFase6;
} Fases;
```

y estoy obteniendo la trama como sigue

```
char tramaEntrada[] = "iRTC 02 34 56";
```

tramaEntrada[] simula la trama recibida a través del I2C y está comprobado que funciona igual a la recepción original.

uso la función sscanf() para separar los datos de la siguiente manera: iRTC es el comando, la hora es el número 02, el minuto es el número 34 y el segundo es el número 56 (instante de tiempo de inicio de evento). Como sscanf() solo admite punteros, instancié un puntero a estructura en main() donde lo uso inicialmente para otras operaciones, de la siguiente manera

```
Fases *fases;
```

y lo instancio como "extern" desde la libería (mensaje.c) de usuario donde tengo definida la función que me va a determinar el comando a ejecutar, instanciado de la siguiente manera:

```
extern Fases *fases;
```

el arreglo que me almacena todos los comandos definidos (también en mensaje.c) disponibles es el siguiente

```
char comandos[] = "aSHOiRTCdRTCfMAUfMTRfAFXfAFT";
```

y la función (en mensaje.c) con la cual discrimino los comandos es llamada Selec_Opera() y está definida de la siguiente manera

```
void Selec_Opera(char *ent)
{
    volatile uint8_t pos = 0;
    volatile uint8_t lugar = 1;
    uint8_t eComando[T_COMANDO + 1] = {0};
    while(pos < T_COMANDO)
    {
        eComando[pos] = ent[pos];
        pos++;
    }
    pos = strindex(comandos, (char *) eComando);
    for(; T_COMANDO*lugar <= pos; lugar++);
    switch(lugar)
    {
    case 0x01:
    {
        pos = 1;
    }
    break;
    case 0x02:
    {
        pos = sscanf(ent, "%s%[*^ ]%hhd %[*^ ]%hhd %[*^ ]%hhd", eComando,
                 &fases->hSistema.Hours,
                 &fases->hSistema.Minutes,
                 &fases->hSistema.Seconds);
    }
    break;
    case 0x03:
    {
        pos = 3;
    }
    break;
    case 0x04:
    {
        pos = 4;
    }
    break;
    case 0x05:
    {
        pos = 5;
    }
    break;
    case 0x06:
    {
        pos = 6;
    }
    break;
    case 7:
    {
        pos = 7;
    }
    break;
    default:
    {
        pos = 25;
    }
    break;
    }
}
```

La función es llamada desde el main() así

```
Selec_Opera((char *) tramaEntrada);
```

El problema está específicamente con sscanf() debido a que no está extrayendo el dato completo, ingreso el arreglo tramaEntrada[] descrito al principio y solo extrae el "iRTC" y el "02", además me está retornando un 2 lo cual concuerda con la cantidad de datos que extrae y esto finalmente me hace pensar que la función considera que el resto del arreglo no concuerda o está viendo el espacio en blanco como fin del arreglo y termina el trabajo, el problema es que no tengo idea de por cuál razón no está viendo el resto de los datos, he probado en otro programa mucho más simple el cual escribo a continuación

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    u_int8_t hora, minuto, segundo;
    char comando[20];
    char trama[] = "iRTC 02 34 56";
    sscanf( trama, "%s %hhd %hhd %hhd", comando, &hora, &minuto, &segundo);
    printf("Comando: %s\n hora: %d, minuto: %d, segundo: %d\n", trama, hora, minuto, segundo);
    return(0);
}
```

y funciona a la perfección de esta manera, separando todos los datos correctamente y almacenándolos en las variables dispuestas para ello, entonces, qué estoy haciendo mal y/o como lo puedo arreglar?.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda brindada.

Actualización: Probé la sugerencia de @Candid Moe y el compilador me está dando la siguiente advertencia

```
../Core/Src/mensaje.c:42:32: warning: format '%hd' expects argument of type 
'short int *', but argument 5 has type 'uint8_t * {aka unsigned char *}' [Wformat=]pos = sscanf(ent, "%s %hd %hd %hd", eComando,
                          ~~^
                          %hhd
```

incluso el mismo compilador me sugiere utilizar %hhd, en el programa de prueba me está dando la primera como en el resultado de @Candid Moe pero las variables hora, minuto y segundo las está llenando con cero. El programa en el que necesito llenar los punteros a estructura sigue dando el resultado inicial si lo ejecuto con los formatos cambiados a %hd pero con la advertencia de más arriba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualizado el 30/08/2020:

Finalmente lo pude resolver de la siguiente manera: declaré unas variables dato1, dato2 y dato3 de tipo "int" porque el especificador de formato %d exige un "int *" para retornar el dato, como el microcontrolador que estoy usando es de 32 bits intenté usar uint32_t pero igualmente me daba advertencias así que lo dejé como "int", luego cambié los punteros a estructura por estructuras y le asigné a los miembros de estas estructuras el contenido de las variables dato1, dato 2 y dato 3 haciendo los casting respectivos a uint8_t. A continuación el código relevante de la función Selec_Opera():

```
void Selec_Opera(char *ent)
{
    volatile uint8_t pos = 0;
    uint8_t eComando[T_COMANDO + 1] = {0};
    int dato1 = 0, dato2 = 0, dato3 = 0;
    while(pos < T_COMANDO)
    {
        eComando[pos] = ent[pos];
        pos++;
    }
    pos = strindex(comandos, (char *) eComando);
    switch(pos)
    {
    case 0:
    {
        pos = 1;
    }
    break;
    case 4:
    {
        pos = sscanf(ent, "%s %d %d %d", eComando, &dato1, &dato2, &dato3);
        fases.hSistema.Hours = (uint8_t) dato1;
        fases.hSistema.Minutes = (uint8_t) dato2;
        fases.hSistema.Seconds = (uint8_t) dato3;
        __asm("nop");
    }
    break;
```

si en vez de utilizar como argumento de sscanf() las variables dato1, dato2 y dato3 uso como argumento de sscanf() los miembros de las estructuras también asigna los valores correctos pero da advertencias porque va a truncar el dato devuelto.

Lo importante es que debí utilizar obligatoriamente %d como especificador de formato para leer los números de la trama.

Comment: El problema es que yo mismo resolví mi problema y no puedo marcar mi propia respuesta como la solución, el sistema no me lo permite

Comment: Gracias a todos, ya me dejó

Answer (score 0):

El formato del sscanf parece tener problemas. Funciona usando

```
sscanf( trama, "%s %hd %hd %hd", comando, &hora, &minuto, &segundo);
```

Cambie los formatos `%hhd` por simplemente `%hd`. No se que pueda significar `%hhd`.

El formato "%hd" reconoce string de largo arbitrario, lo que no hace daño en este caso.

Este es el programa de prueba:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    short unsigned int hora, minuto, segundo;
    char comando[20];
    char trama[] = "iRTC 022 34 56";
    sscanf( trama, "%s %hd %hd %hd", comando, &hora, &minuto, &segundo);
    printf("Comando: %s\n hora: %d, minuto: %d, segundo: %d\n", trama, hora, minuto, segundo);
    return(0);
}
```

produce

```
Comando: iRTC 022 34 56
 hora: 22, minuto: 34, segundo: 56
```

**Segunda prueba**

Usando el formato original,

```
sscanf( trama, "%s %hhd %hhd %hhd", comando, &hora, &minuto, &segundo);
```

obtenemos

```
Comando: iRTC 022 34 56
 hora: 21270, minuto: 21794, segundo: 56
```

Comment: probé tu sugerencia y escribí el resultado a partir de la edición "Actualización" de mi publicación original, desafortunadamente no funcionó.